# Writing a ParseKit grammar with a varying number of fields (in order)

Tags: objective-c, parsekit

I'm not super experienced in writing grammars, but let's say I have a record type like these:
(examples)

```
record # 1 source ages params A = 1 and b = 2 fields are A, B, C with values 1, 2, 3;
record # 2;
record # 3 source ages;
record # 4 params A = 1 and b = 2 fields are A, B, C with values 1, 2, 3;
record # 5 source ages fields are A, B, C with values 1, 2, 3;
record # 6 with values 1, 2, 3;
```

Basically:

1. Must start with "record # Number" and end with a semi-colon.
2. May contain 0 or 1 captures in the following order:
3. source dataset
4. parameters of dataset
5. fields from dataset
6. values from dataset

Here is my grammar, it's not working:

--- start grammar:

```
@start = record;

record = 'record' '#' numeric rest* ';';
rest = 'source' alphanumeric paramsAndOrFieldsAndOrWithValues*;
paramsAndOrFieldsAndOrWithValues = (paramsList)? (fieldsList)? (valuesList)?;
paramsList = 'params' alpha expr numeric ('and' alpha expr numeric)*;
fieldsList = 'fields' 'are' alpha (comma alpha)*;
valuesList = 'with' 'values' numeric (comma numeric)*;


alpha = Word;
numeric = Number;
alphanumeric = (alpha | numeric | '_' | '.');
comma = ',';
expr = '=';
```

--- end grammar

@"Developer from ParseKit", can you please help me?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer of [ParseKit](http://parsekit.com) here.

Your grammar is a little bit off. I worked up a grammar which matches your example input. I've run this using the `DebugApp` target, and can confirm that it works for your example.

```
@start = records;
records = record+;
record = prefix source? params? fields? values? suffix;

prefix = 'record' '#' Number;
suffix = ';';

// source
source = 'source' Word;

// params
params = 'params' expr ('and' expr)*;
expr = name '=' Number;
name = Word;

// fields
fields = 'fields' 'are' name (',' name)*;

// values
values = 'with' 'values' val (',' val)*;

val = Number;
```

Comment: record # 1 source hello fields are A, B, C ;
fails to parse fields, any idea, why?  using your grammar

Comment: Hm, that's working fine here for me against my grammar. Here's a printout from my Record callback:
`-[DebugAppDelegate parser:didMatchRecord:] [record, #, 1, source, hello, fields, are, A, ,, B, ,, C, ;]record/#/1/source/hello/fields/are/A/,/B/,/C/;^`

Comment: Oddly, in the "ParseKit Demo" it doesn't show the 'fields' branch/tree... possibly a bug in the PK Demo app?

Here's a screenshot: http://imgur.com/bjb10

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry, that DemoApp tree thing is really not complete. Do not trust what it shows you, as it cannot reliably draw all grammars. It is quite buggy actually. Just add the Assembler callback methods to your Assembler class and you'll see they are called correctly for my grammar above (at least they are here).

Comment: Is PKParseTree complete?  BTW, I really love ParseKit.  You should think about accepting donations...

Comment: Sorry no, the PKParseTree stuff is really not complete. You'll notice that stuff is only in the DemoApp, and not included in ParseKit proper. I've never gotten around to completing it. And it's buggy. As for donations, Thanks, glad you like PK. But I'd much rather you marked my answer above as 'Accepted' so I can get some StackOverflow credit :).